# Services not visible in SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express, sql-server-config-manager

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express 32 bit. I have installed it successfully but when I try connect with SQL Server I am getting an error

[image]

Then I thought to turn the services ON from SQL Server Configuration Manager but I am not able to see any

[image]

Also my SQL Server Configuration Manager shows some corrupt as below:

[image]

Comment: SQL Server **Management Studio** is ***ONLY*** the management GUI tool - but ***NOT*** the actual **database engine!** That's why you're not seeing any "SQL Server" services - just simply because you didn't actually **install ANY** database engine! You need to install a **full** version of SQL Server Express - the "With Tools" or "With Advanced Services" versions also include the Management Studio.

Comment: @Garvit Gupta did you find the solution of your problem ,actually i have the same problem and I have also the same state as shown in your screen shots.Please reply if you find your solution

Comment: I have the Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install SQL Server database engine. Here is the link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Express edition will be good.

Although this question was posted two years ago, most of the new developers face this problem. I had the same issue and I hope this will help other developers as well.