# Protocols for MSSQLSERVER Not Visible in SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, remote-access, vpn, remote-server

I am trying to make a remote connection to a SQL Server database and have been having problems.  When trying to connect it keeps timing out.

I have consulted the following post:

[Services not visible in SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189073/services-not-visible-in-sql-server-configuration-manager)

I have taken steps outlined in the following questions:

[Which IP to Use to Remote Connect to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956391/which-ip-to-use-to-remote-connect-to-sql-server)

[Connect to SQL Server from Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954947/connect-to-sql-server-from-web-app)

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46599/how-to-remote-connect-to-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment78624_46599

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193975/how-to-expose-sql-server-hosted-on-intranet-to-connect-remotely?noredirect=1#comment377827_193975

At this point I think I am being blocked by a hardware firewall, or that I don't have all the proper modules installed on the SQL Server.  [image]

When looking at online tutorials such as this: https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/stories/insights/2015/tcpip-is-disabled-by-default-in-microsoft-sql-server-2014

It seems that `Protocols for MSSQLSERVER` should be visible from this dropdown.

I have tried installing all the SQL Server related packages from the Web Platform Installer.

Comment: It looks like you have a named instance of SQL Server Express Edition installed named SQLEXPRESS. You should see a pane to the right that lists the protocols for that instance when the item on the left is selected.

Comment: You should first establish whether you can connect locally. Knowing that information halves the amount of investigation required.

Comment: The `MSSQLSERVER` service is for the **default, unnamed** instance of SQL Server - **IF** it is installed. From your screen shot, it appears as if you've only installed the SQL Server **Express** edition to its default - `SQLEXPRESS`. To get the `MSSQLSERVER` service, you need to install another SQL Server instance and make it the **default** instance (which has no explicit name and shows up as `MSSQLSERVER` in Configuration Manager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLEXPRESS` and `SQLSERVER` are two different software packages and must be installed separately.